# Can't read property 'clearRect' of undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I saw this question was asked before but it didn't solve my problem! I'm new to JavaScript and I tried to solve it almost a day now but still can't.

I have a class and function like this:

```js
let playerTank = {width: 80, height: 80, speed: 2};

class Tank {
    constructor(canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    }
    draw() {
        this.ctx.drawImage(.....);
        this.ctx.stroke();
    }
    update(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {
            this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
            this.draw();
            // do something ...
        }
    }
}

function main() {
    let canvas = document.getElementByID("my-canvas");
    
    let tank = new Tank(canvas);
    tank.draw();

    window.addEventListener("keydown", tank.update, true);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", tank.update, false);
}

main();
```

Here is my problem! When I ever i click the key I get these errors:

```
can't read property 'clearRect' of undefined
can't read property 'draw' of undefined
```

I really don't understand why I can't access the attributes and function within the same class?

Comment: You've set the context of the parameter in your `constructor`. Change `this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")` to `this.canvas...`

Comment: Try changing `document.getElementByID` to `document.getElementById` (case sensitive).

Comment: @kmp hey! it solved one of the problem but now it said `this.draw()` is not a function. Why?

Comment: @sbgib it's just a mistake when i typed it up here

Comment: You named your function `draw()`

Comment: @kmp it was a mistake but now I call `this.draw()` but it still give me same error

Comment: Check your draw method. Is it working when you call `tank.draw()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lost context:

```js
class Tank {
    draw() {
      console.log('draw');
    }
    update() {
       this.draw();
    }
}

const tank = new Tank();

// Call method of instance. Works
tank.draw(); 

// Set this method as listener. 
// Dont works, cause method called from event context (window)
window.addEventListener("event1", tank.update, true); 

// Set anonimous listener, which call method. Works
window.addEventListener("event2", () => tank.update(), true); 

// Set method as listener and bind right context. Also works
window.addEventListener("event3", tank.update.bind(tank), true); 

window.dispatchEvent(new Event("event1"));
window.dispatchEvent(new Event("event2"));
window.dispatchEvent(new Event("event3"));
```